# Does the second positive solution (besides $x = 1$) of the equation $e^{x^2-1}=x^3-x\ln x$ have a closed form?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, special-functions, closed-form, lambert-w

> Does the equation $$e^{x^2-1}=x^3-x\ln x$$ have a closed form solution ?

The given equation has $2$ positive real roots. Graphically

[image]

[image]

It is not hard to see that $x=1$ is a rational solution. The difficulty lies in finding the second irrational root. Wolfram Alpha gives an approximate solution for the second root: $$x\approx 0.45076365201730712954...$$

The notion that the second root is irrational is my assumption.  Presumably, this root is irrational.

Questions.

How do we know if an irrational root has a closed form?  If this solution does not have closed form, with what theory can we prove it ?

Clarification: By closed form it is meant the elementary functions and the Lambert W function.

Comment: Thank you for your edit Bruno B !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking logarithm on both side of
$$
e^{x^2-1}=x^3-x \ln x,
$$
we have $$
x^2-\ln x=1+\ln \left(x^2-\ln x\right)\iff y=1+\ln y \tag*{(*)}  ,
$$
where $y=x^2-\ln x.$

Since $$y=1+\ln y \iff y=1,$$
therefore
\begin{aligned} 
x^2-\ln x =1  \Rightarrow & e^{x^2}=x \cdot e \\
\Rightarrow & e^{-1}=x e^{-x^2} \\
\Rightarrow & e^{-2}=x^2 e^{-2 x^2} \\
\Rightarrow & -2 e^{-2}=-2 x^2 e^{-2 x^2} \\
\Rightarrow & -2 x^2=W\left(-2 e^{-2}\right) \\
\Rightarrow & x=\sqrt{-\frac{W\left(-2 e^{-2}\right)}{2}} \doteq 0.450764
\end{aligned}

where $W(.)$ is the [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: +1 This is simpler since it uses the Lambert function only once. [Verified by WA.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5BSqrt%5B-%281%2F2%29+ProductLog%5B-2E%5E%28-2%29%5D+%5D%2C20%5D)

Answer (score 4):

$$e^{x^2-1}=x^3-x\ln x$$
We can take the logarithm on both sides.
$$x^2-1=\ln x+\ln(x^2-\ln x)\\
x^2-\ln x=1+\ln(x^2-\ln x)$$
We can make a substitution.
\begin{eqnarray}
u&=&x^2-\ln x\\
e^u&=&\frac{e^{x^2}}x\\
xe^{-x^2}&=&e^{-u}\\
x^2e^{-2x^2}&=&e^{-2u}\\
-2x^2e^{-2x^2}&=&-2e^{-2u}\\
-2x^2&=&W(-2e^{-2u})\\
x&=&\sqrt{\frac{-W(-2e^{-2u})}2}
\end{eqnarray}
Now, solve for $u.$
\begin{eqnarray}
u&=&1+\ln u\\
\ln u-u&=&-1\\
ue^{-u}&=&e^{-1}\\
-ue^{-u}&=&-e^{-1}\\
u&=&-W(-e^{-1})\\
x&=&\sqrt{\frac{-W(-2e^{2W(-e^{-1})})}2}
\end{eqnarray}
There is an infinite nunber of branches of the [Lambert function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Only two suffice for real inputs. [Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Csqrt%7B%5Cfrac%7B-productlog%280%2C-2e%5E%7B2productlog%280%2C-e%5E%7B-1%7D%29%7D%29%7D2%7D) is the non-trivial value, using the $0$ branch, $W_0(\cdot)$. And [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Csqrt%7B%5Cfrac%7B-productlog%28-1%2C-2e%5E%7B2productlog%28-1%2C-e%5E%7B-1%7D%29%7D%29%7D2%7D) is the trivial value using the $-1$ branch, $W_{-1}(\cdot).$